# Spark Batch Avro Deserialization: Malformed data. Length is negative

Tags: apache-spark, avro, confluent-schema-registry, spark-avro

I am doing some batch processing on Kafka through Spark. The record as serialized as Avro. I am trying to deserialize the value using the exact schema in the message itself but am getting a malformed record exception. Here's my code:

```
    Dataset<Row> load = sparkSession
            .read()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", (String) kafkaConfiguration.consumerProperties().get("bootstrap.servers"))
            .option("subscribe", kafkaConfiguration.topicsAsCSV(","))
            .load();

    var schema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("schema.avsc")));

    load.select(from_avro(col("value"), schema)).write().json("/tmp/spark/json");
```

Note that the schema is copied as-is from the record's value itself.

However, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -20
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:336)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:263)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:272)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readString(ResolvingDecoder.java:214)
```

What's the reason behind this error and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I need more information.
But, I have a similar issue when I tried to consume avro messages from Confluent's Kafka. It's generate a message with 5 bytes to store the SchemaRegitryID from SchemaRegistry service and the avro's content it's in the the rest of message.

```
# python example to slice bytes
schema_id = message[:5]
content = message[5:]
```

More information in https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#parse-bytes with pyspark insted of Java/Scala (sorry).

Comment: I have actually tried skipping the first five bytes as well but to no avail :/